# How to efficiently group, sum and sort this mysql result?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm pulling a grouping of comment types and their totals from a mySQL database.  The result set looks like:

> ID - NAME - TOTAL
>   0  - GENERAL - 4
>   3  - MEANINGFUL - 9
>   4 - MISC - 5

In my output to the end user, however, I want to sum the totals for GENERAL and MISC, IDs 0 and 4.  How should I efficiently do this?  The problem I'm seeing is that ID 0 might not be in every result and the same thing for ID 4.

Any suggestions?

My query is:

```
SELECT a.fk_type_id as ID, count(a.fk_type_id) as TOTAL, b.vch_name as NAME
FROM comments a
LEFT JOIN comments_types b ON a.fk_type_id = b.id
WHERE a.entry = X
GROUP BY a.fk_type_id
```

So my end-user result should look like:

> GENERAL/MISC - 9
>   MEANINGFUL - 9

Comment: What is the query that produces this?

Comment: If in results line doesn't exixst then TOTAL is 0. Or you want somthing other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make it easy on you and MySQL and split it out like this:

```
(SELECT a.fk_type_id as ID, COUNT(a.fk_type_id) as TOTAL, b.vch_name as NAME
FROM comments a
JOIN comments_types b ON a.fk_type_id = b.id
WHERE a.entry = X AND a.fk_type_id <> 0 AND a.fk_type_id <> 4
GROUP BY a.fk_type_id)
UNION ALL
(SELECT a.fk_type_id as ID, COUNT(a.fk_type_id) as TOTAL, 'GENERAL/MISC' as NAME
FROM comments a
JOIN comments_types b ON a.fk_type_id = b.id
WHERE a.entry = X AND (a.fk_type_id = 0 OR a.fk_type_id = 4)
GROUP BY a.fk_type_id)
```

I changed your `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN` because we're only counting comments with a type.

You might improve this query, assuming an index on `fk_type_id`, by making 'MISC' type '1' instead of type '4', so you could do something like `a.fk_type_id < 2` instead of (`a.fk_type_id = 0 OR a.fk_type_id = 4`) and `a.fk_type_id > 1` instead of `a.fk_type_id <> 0 AND a.fk_type_id <> 4`.

If you're utilizing indexes instead of scanning rows, performing two separate queries that return different results won't affect performance.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query -

```
SELECT
  IF(name = 'GENERAL' OR name = 'MISC', 'GENERAL/MISC', name) new_name
  , SUM(total)
FROM
  comments
GROUP BY
  new_name
```

You may write your custom `new_name` field.

Answer (score 0):

This will sum multiple entries of GENERAL and MISC

```
SELECT SUM(TOTAL) FROM tablename WHERE NAME='GENERAL' OR NAME='MISC';
```

Comment: But i need the other potential IDs returned, too.  So in the example above, my end-user might see GENERAL/MISC - 9, MEANINGFUL - 9

Comment: @Mike, then why not do your original query and add the General and Misc totals yourself?